# HTML Form: How to get selected option NOT value in PHP

Tags: php, html

Could anyone explain how I can select the value within the  tags of a form and using PHP and not the actual value parameter?

e.g.

```
<option value="#NOT THIS#">#THIS!#</option>
```

Thanks

Comment: by parent dom  select name

Comment: Depends on what you're using to parse the HTML

Comment: You didn't mention if you can use client side code to solve this issue. In which case you have a plethora of solutions. If you're strictly using PHP then it depends. Are the one populating the select values? Then it's just a matter of storing the list and fetching the human friendly value.

Comment: Just don't declare the `value` attribute -- then the text will be used by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();
</script>
```

if this will not work for you, try this:

```
<script>
    $('#yourdropdownid').find('option:selected').text();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select  name="select" >
 <option value='1'>This 1</option>
 <option value='2'>this 2</option>
</select>​
```

and Script

```
$(function(){    
    $("select[name='select']").change(function(){
      alert($(this).find('option:selected').text());       
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one. It's simple. You can select option with `id="someName"` and focuse it on words like you put ( #THIS!#").

```
<script>
     $("#someID").change(function(element) {
                            var selectedValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
                            if (selectedValue === "#THIS!#") {
            // do something 
         }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot get the value inside options tag using Php. When the form is submitted it only sends the value attribute of the selectbox to the server